# How can I get the unzip result code in remote sever in my bash script?

Tags: shell, expect

I try to unzip a .zip file in remote sever by local script.
code like this:

```
expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn ssh root@remote "cd /var/www/ && unzip -o my.zip -d ./dest || echo $?"
expect {
"*(yes/no)*" { send "yes\r"; expect "*password*" { send "password\r" } }
"*password*" { send "password\r"}
}
expect eof
EOF
```

The result code is zero whether it is an error or not.
I want to get the result code and use it in external of EOF.
But I don't know how to do.
Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: If you ditch `expect`, passing the exit value through will be automatic. If you **must** automate password entry (and it's better if you don't), use `sshpass` instead.

Comment: well, `|| echo $?` actually prevents it from being passed through as well, since it'll pass the exit status of `echo` as that of ssh, and `echo` generally succeeds.

Comment: You'd avoid *that* issue if you replaced `|| echo $?` with, say, `|| { retval=$?; echo "$retval"; exit "$retval"; }` so you still exit with a nonzero status even after the `echo`.

Comment: Actually, just to be clear -- when you say "the result code is zero", do you mean the status emitted by `echo`, or the status left in `$?` after `expect` exits?

Comment: (Also, there's no point to use `expect` to automate answering ssh's questions about whether to save a host key -- you can just tell it not to prompt; ie. with `ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new'` or, if you're more careless about security, `'StrictHostKeyChecking no'`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to improve my code. I think `sshpass` is not suitable for me because of the security reason. Public key is also not allowed. So... only expect.

Comment: Well, I finally use `sshpass` solved this question. Thanks @Charles Duffy